# Классификация кошек и собак в нейронке

Tags: python, python-3.x, нейронные-сети, keras, классификация

Обучил нейронку, кошек и собак на фото правильно классифицирует, но что-либо где их нет не верно относит к одной категории и при этом выдает вероятность соостветствия 90%+

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

# Каталог с данными для обучения
train_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/train'
# Каталог с данными для проверки
val_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/val'
# Каталог с данными для тестирования
test_dir = 'C:\Projects\python\dogorcat\cats_vs_dogs/test'
# Размеры изображения
img_width, img_height = 150, 150
# Размерность тензора на основе изображения для входных данных в нейронную сеть
# backend Tensorflow, channels_last
input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
# Количество эпох
epochs = 30
# Размер мини-выборки
batch_size = 16
# Количество изображений для обучения
nb_train_samples = 17500
# Количество изображений для проверки
nb_validation_samples = 3750
# Количество изображений для тестирования
nb_test_samples = 3750

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

val_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='categorical')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=val_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

scores = model.evaluate_generator(test_generator, nb_test_samples // batch_size)

print("Сохраняем сеть")
# Сохраняем сеть для последующего использования
# Генерируем описание модели в формате json
model_json = model.to_json()
json_file = open("cvd_model.json", "w")
# Записываем архитектуру сети в файл
json_file.write(model_json)
json_file.close()
# Записываем данные о весах в файл
model.save_weights("cvd_model.h5")
print("Сохранение сети завершено")
```

Как заставить фотки без собак и кошек не учитывать?

Comment: Как вы подбирали количество сверток, почему именно 2 по 32 и одна 64?

Comment: @Владислав, я это где-то в интернете глянул, в другом месте слышал, что это чисто практикой подбирается, не знаю как это объективно по каким-то критериям подбирать

Comment: Вы наверно это взяли из курса Андрея Сызокина :) Я как раз смотрю его уроки, и там этот пример. Вот тоже читал, что все таки нет чистого шаблона, все делается методом подборок.

Comment: @Владислав в том числе из Созыкина, но он многое не объясняет, я прервался на середине и стал читать документацию

Comment: А мне наоборот :) я прочел книгу по глубокому обучению, плюс прочитал и просмотрел курс OpenDAtaScince и когда начал что-то пытаться на Kaggle, многое было не понятно, и вот вчера посмотрел полный курс Созыкина, теперь даже многое стало понятно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему проще всего будет добавить третью категорию `unknown` - сложить туда картинки не содержащие ни кошек ни собак и обучить ИНС на наборе данных содержащих три категории.

Кроме того если вы используете `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`, то в качестве функции активации на последнем слое следует использовать `activation='softmax'`, т.к. `sigmoid` используется для задач **бинарной** классификации.